WPF binding to DataGrid works partially column headers are generated but items don't get listed
I am building an app in mvvm style and object factory as for background I am in study so pretty new.
Upfront sorry cause of my study parts of the code got written in German.
Problem
I try to bind an ObservableCollection<Betrag> BeitragsListe to a dataGrid, but on reviewing the outcome, it generates the column headers as expected, but it doesn't fill the single items in the grid so DataContext and Itemsource are correct that is what think at least.
View:
<Window x:Class="Essensausgleich.contributionWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Essensausgleich.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="contributionWindow" Height="235" Width="382" >
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            Name="DataGridContribution"
            ItemsSource="{Binding BeitragsListe}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            />
    </Grid>
</Window>

View model aka Anwendung (just the related parts):
Properties -- the OnProperty and OnCollection are there because of trying around:
public ObservableCollection<Betrag> BeitragsListe
{
     get => this._BeitragsListe;
     set
     {
         this._BeitragsListe = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
         OnCollectionChanged(
new System.Collections.Specialized.
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
System.Collections.Specialized.
NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
         Log.WriteLine($"{BeitragsListe.GetType().Name} has changed");
     }
}

private ObservableCollection<Betrag> _BeitragsListe = new ObservableCollection<Betrag>();

Method used
/// <summary>
/// Opens The window and fills the Datagrid with the Current
/// selectedInhabitant to display the total Expenses
/// </summary>
public void OpenContributioWindow()
{
     Log.WriteLine("ButtonAuflistung Clicked");
     var vm = this.Kontext.Produziere<ViewModel.Anwendung>();

     vm.Anzeigen<contributionWindow>();

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InhabitantsSelected))
     {
         if (InhabitantsSelected == Bewohner1Name)
         {       
             this.BeitragsListe = new ObservableCollection<Betrag>(bewohner1.Einzelbetraege);         
         }
         else if (InhabitantsSelected == Bewohner2Name)
         {
             this.BeitragsListe = new ObservableCollection<Betrag>(bewohner2.Einzelbetraege);
         }
         else
         {
             Log.WriteLine($"No Inhabitant selected or not found, Selcted:{InhabitantsSelected}");
         }
     }
}

Struct Betrag - gets added to the list:
/// <summary>
/// struct to serve as single entry for the Bewohner object
/// </summary>
public struct Betrag
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Category string of Betrag
     /// </summary>
     public string kategorie {  get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Amount in decimal of Betrag
     /// </summary>
     public decimal wert {  get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// constructor for the Betrag Struct
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="k"></param>
     /// <param name="w"></param>
     public Betrag(string k, decimal w)
     {
         kategorie = k;
         wert = w;
     }       
}

When debugging, I checked that the BeitragsListe does have the expected entries, for example BeitragsListe[0] is a Betrag object consisting of wert=10, kategorie="Hofa" //one is a decimal and the other a string
xamlLiveView
ContributionWindow with Headers without values
DebugInfoBeitragsListe

Problem solved
The datakontext was attached but not in a way that it updates the changes in the Viewmodel so by the Time that the Datagrid was ready to accept changes in the BeitragsListe it only found the structur to creat the Headers but never got to see the new Items.
took me 3 days Learning is hard

Try binding to the Grid's DataContext directly.
In your OpenContributioWindow() function, right after you set the this.BeitragsListe, try adding DataGridContribution.DataContext = this.BeitragsListe; (assuming that this code lives in your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, or equivalent thereof). This should bind the data to the grid and display the appropriate values to the screen.

To Clarify its a Mvvm Model i dont have logic in my ContributionWindow.cs this is all in the Anwendung.cs (my ViewModel) there is also the place where the Datacontext gets attached to the new Window.
i tryd your suggestions but it did not change anything.

New Founding:
If i switch the
ObservableCollection<Betrag> BeitragsListe
to a
List<Betrag> BeitragsListe
it does work as expected but why, i implemented the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
the same way do i need to change something else to my
ObservableCollection to update the ui
